# Trouble making jQuery.Parallax and jQuery.Skrollr work in harmony. (Iterating through backgrounds when window scrolls.)

Tags: jquery, animation, scroll, parallax

I'm coding the visual part of a website and I've hit a snag. I'm trying to keep it mostly CSS for greater compatibility, but I do want to use some jQuery: chiefly for when the user scrolls the window, hence Parallax and Skrollr.

As you know, Parallax allows for, among other things, the scrolling of a background at a speed relative to that of the scrolling of the window itself. This produces and effect of 3D planes. This is why I'm using Parallax: in order to scroll certain backgrounds as if they were physically behind the main content.

Skroller works to trigger certain animations at certain points of the window scroll position.

I'm using both together in order to have **an animated background that animates when the user scrolls the window and, at the same time, scrolls at a speed relative to that of the window scroll.** Perhaps this animation will help exemplify this in a way that might be clearer:

[image: Parallax and Skrollr working together in harmony.]

As you can see, when user scrolls the main window, the content (Top Window) scroll as per usual. However, the group of backgrounds (Bgs 1, 2 and 3) scroll, as well, but at a slower rate (this is Parallax working). Although you can't quite notice the "slower rate" in this animation, you should be able to note that, simultaneously, as they are moving in unison, their displays are going from `block` to `none`, first one, then the other, then the other, etc., and back again, forming a loop which animates through all these backgrounds as the user continues scrolling (this is Skrollr working).

So far, so good. I have one of these sets of backgrounds on the upper part of the page and everything is going fine. However, a way down, I'm having issues with the second set of backgrounds. This second set is displayed as seen below: instead of being one on top of the other, the individual background layers' `background-position`, which should always start from 0, is pushed down about 200px. The image should show the issue very clearly.

[image: Issue]

As you can see, these two backgrounds (Bgs 2 and 3) should appear one on top of the other. However, one is clearly kicked way down, and so are the rest of the individual bg layers that come on top. Only the first or under-most layer appears as it should.

The HTML codes for both sets are almost identical (the only difference is that set 1 us inside a a general wrapping DIV, whereas set 2 is just as is within the `<body>`:

**HTML SET 1**

```
<div id="head_wrapper">
  <div class="background_head bg1_1"></div>
  <div class="background_head bg1_2" data-0="display: none;"  data-50="display: block;" data-400="display: none;" data-450="display: block;" data-800="display: none;"></div>
  <div class="background_head bg1_3" data-0="display: none;" data-100="display: block;" data-350="display: none;" data-500="display: block;" data-750="display: none;"></div>
  <div class="background_head bg1_4" data-0="display: none;" data-150="display: block;" data-300="display: none;" data-550="display: block;" data-700="display: none;"></div>
  <div class="background_head bg1_5" data-0="display: none;" data-200="display: block;" data-250="display: none;" data-600="display: block;" data-650="display: none;"></div>
</div>
```

**HTML SET 2**

The CSS for each set is as follows:

**CSS SET 1**

```
#top_wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#head_wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1133px;
  height: 733px;
}
.background_head {
  background-position: 50% 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 1133px;
  height: 733px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.bg1_1 {
  background-image: url(../img/bgs/bg1_1.jpg);
  z-index: 11;
}
.bg1_2 {
   background-image: url(../img/bgs/bg1_2.jpg);
   z-index: 12;
}
.bg1_3 {
   background-image: url(../img/bgs/bg1_3.jpg);
   z-index: 13;
}
.bg1_4 {
  background-image: url(../img/bgs/bg1_4.jpg);
  z-index: 14;
}
.bg1_5 {
  background-image: url(../img/bgs/bg1_5.jpg);
  z-index: 15;
}
```

**CSS SET 2**

```
.background_wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 1133px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.background_content {
  background-position: 50% 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 1133px;
  height: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.bg2_1 {
  background-image: url(../img/bgs/bg2_1.jpg);
  z-index: 21;
}
.bg2_2 {
  background-image: url(../img/bgs/bg2_2.jpg);
  z-index: 22;
}
.bg2_3 {
  background-image: url(../img/bgs/bg2_3.jpg);
  z-index: 23;
}
.bg2_4 {
  background-image: url(../img/bgs/bg2_4.jpg);
  z-index: 24;
}
.bg2_5 {
  background-image: url(../img/bgs/bg2_5.jpg);
  z-index: 25;
}
```

And, finally, this is the jQuery that binds Parallax and Skrollr to all this good stuff:

**JQUERY SETS 1 and 2**

```
skrollr.init({
  forceHeight: false,
  smoothScrolling: true
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bg1_1').parallax("50%", -0.75);
  $('.bg1_2').parallax("50%", -0.75);
  $('.bg1_3').parallax("50%", -0.75);
  $('.bg1_4').parallax("50%", -0.75);
  $('.bg1_5').parallax("50%", -0.75);
  $('.bg2_1').parallax("50%", -0.3);
  $('.bg2_2').parallax("50%", -0.3);
  $('.bg2_3').parallax("50%", -0.3);
  $('.bg2_4').parallax("50%", -0.3);
  $('.bg2_5').parallax("50%", -0.3);
})
```

I believe that's all I can show you. I hope it's clear enough. I've been researching all today and I can't seem to find any reference to these two jQuery plugins being used together. Heaven know Skrollr has no documentation, at least none that I know of, so it's difficult to figure out how it works without taking apart the code itself. Anyway, that's why I'm asking here, because apparently no one has already run into this issue... perhaps these two plugins are not compatible... I would have thought that at first, but because one of my background sets is working fine, I guess the issue is either something I'm missing in all the stuff I've just left here for you guys to check and help me out or... I don't know: something else.

Anyway, any kind of help from you guys will be very much appreciated!

Comment: skrollr documentation https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr#documentation

Comment: Upvoted merely for the animation! I don't otherwise have time to help right now.